# VBScript can't find object in .NET dll

Tags: vb.net, dll, vbscript

I created a .NET DLL `MyCustomLib` in Visual Studio 2015, consisting of a class

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
<ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)>
<Guid("D42A39C8-01EC-4467-9AE3-DC22DCA895A4")>
Public Class MyClass
   Public Sub New()
       Dim frm As New MyForm
       frm.Show()
   End Sub
End Class
```

and second class

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
<ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)>
<Guid("D42A39C8-01EC-4467-9AE3-DC22DCA895A5")>
Public Class MyForm
  Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
      InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

  End Sub
End Class
```

So, both have a parameterless constructor, the classes are public.
I build it and register it using `regasm.exe` (the x64 one). Regasm tells me, that registration was successful. 
Then I create a VBScript file to call the DLL:

```
'TestCall.vbs
Dim oObject
Set oObject = CreateObject("MyCustomLib.MyClass")
```

When I execute the vbs, I get an error **80070002: The system cannot find the file specified.**
Why do I get this error?

Comment: Also if you have registered the DLL using the x64 version of `regasm.exe` are you then executing the VBScript with the x64 version of `cscript.exe` or `wscript.exe`?

Comment: with wscript. Actually it is working now. But when I try to call a method of my class in vbscript (e.g. oObject.MyFunc()) I get an error "This object doesn't support this property or method: MyFunc" eventhough MyFunc is declared as COMVisible=true